# CSS For Smaller Screens overidden by CSS for Larger Screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to use a responsive grid view to show three items:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">Object 1</div>
    <div class="col-3">Object 1</div>
    <div class="col-3">Object 1</div>
</div>
```

next to each other and if the user's screen is to small to place the three items underneath each other using this piece of css:

```
    [class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      /* For desktop: */
      .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
      .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
      .col-3 {width: 25%;}
      .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
      .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
      .col-6 {width: 50%;}
      .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
      .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
      .col-9 {width: 75%;}
      .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
      .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
      .col-12 {width: 100%;}
    }
```

However when I make my screen smaller my three objects just clump together and in chrome it shows that the widths of their respective columns are still what they would have been for a larger screen.

Comment: Do you have the media query for any screen smaller than 991px?

Comment: No because this is the default size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by changing the flex direction of your container.

```
flex-direction: column;
```

**Edit:**
Working example with flexbox see https://jsfiddle.net/4bc2kqLm/

Comment: but why does the width of the columns not change after the breakpoint

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in the question. My web app is using grid view rather than flexbox

Comment: Can you provide then all of the code in your question please?
FYI: If you want I edited my answer to a working example with flexbox.

Comment: I decided to just change everything to flexbox using bootstrap and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The padding added to all "col-" class adds additional size.
Removing it resolves the issues as demonstrated.

```css
    [class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
      /*  padding: 15px; This padding adds to the size*/
    }

    /*For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      /* For desktop: */
      .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
      .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
      .col-3 {width: 25%;}
      .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
      .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
      .col-6 {width: 50%;}
      .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
      .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
      .col-9 {width: 75%;}
      .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
      .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
      .col-12 {width: 100%;}
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">Object 1</div>
    <div class="col-3">Object 1</div>
    <div class="col-3">Object 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need the padding, add it to the element that will be placed inside your "col-" class.